# jQuery carousel making responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this carousel which is not responsive and need to make it responsive but not sure what to do with it as its a current carousel ive found online that ive been using.

Can someone maybe help me get it responsive? they are just going to be images - many thanks in advance

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNPYqq

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1130x775"></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1130x775"></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1130x775"></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1130x775"></li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1130px;
  height: 775px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

> UPDATE: I have made the CSS 100% in width and height with aut but the JS now needs work i think and dont know what to do here as it sets the ontainer height and width margin stuff to move etc... can someone help me with this please?

Comment: First thing you need to do is to remove all fixed width and make give it in `%age` to make it responsive. Eg: `#slider ul li` has width of `1130px` so this won't fit for smaller device.

Comment: What do you mean %age?

Comment: I set the CSS to width: 100% and heght auto but nothing shows now as the JS is setting width: 100p and height: 0px

Comment: Sorry, I meant percentage. Check my answer I have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the li's width using the document's width and the width of the ul will be taken care of.

**JS**

```
    //get width of document here and set to li
    $('#slider ul li').css({"width":($(document).width()-200)});

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });


    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
```

**CSS**

```
#slider ul li { 

    /* other CSS */

    height: 100%;

  }
```

And for the image to be responsive with respect to the parent

```
#slider ul li img { 
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anpsmn/pen/raVZbm?editors=011)

On Window resize
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/b0v5618w/1/)

Comment: Firstly thanks for your help on this, i just tried to implement and the height is not setting and when i adjust the window size it does not seem to be responsive and resizig the images or slider itself :(

Comment: seems it is setting a width inline css on the LI so will always be fixed width i guess...

Comment: You need to refresh after resizing or you need to make this calculations again on `window.resize`.And what you mean by height is not setting?

Comment: Yes it will set a width inline now as i have changed the logic a bit and adding the li's width through js. `$('#slider ul li').css({"width":($(document).width()-200)});`

Comment: OH ok, do you know how i can do the window resize part at all? again thanks for helping and on my example the right appear to be around 100px in heigh and not showing the full height.

Comment: again, i refreshed with the window being much smaller in width but still setting 1218px width on the LI

Comment: its making it slightly smaller but the smallest it seems to go is 1218 but at ful screen its set to 1463px, i made the window around the same size as mobile but never goes below 1218

Comment: let me add a JS Fiddle to the integrated one, 2 secs

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBaYeG - weird it kind of works.... on can i do the window resize bit and maybe i can work it out on local - again thank you

Comment: <div style="width: 1463px; height: 100px;" id="gallery-slider"> - see here it is setting locally as 100px in height.... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65758/discussion-between-james-brandon-and-anpsmn).

Comment: Added some notes in chat, almost there but its setting the UL height very very big around 7000px

Comment: Ahh its getting height for the whole window and much more on page which is why its setting as 7000px, anyway to do relative to the actual li or make it auto?